# Using a class function from a parameter in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I am wondering if it is possible to pass the name of a function as a parameter, but have a class then call that function. I am aware that you can pass functions as parameters, but that is not what I am curious about. Below is an example of what I am looking for.

```
function passFunction ( functionName ) {

   exampleClass.functionName();
   // Do Something With result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like:

`exampleClass[functionName]()`

but be sure to check its a function first

```
if (typeof exampleClass[functionName] === 'function')
  exampleClass[functionName]()
```

Comment: Sweet! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.